# Jquery works only in jsfidde but not in browsers

Tags: jquery, css

Below is the code which only works in jsfiddle but when i use in browsers it wont works

http://jsfiddle.net/5r6mx/18/
below is the code which i am used in browser which is in the jsfiddle link

//script

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$(".image_stack").delegate('img', 'mouseenter', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('stackphotos')) {

        var $parent = $(this).parent();

$parent.find('div.namehover').addClass('rotate3');
$parent.find('div.namehover').css("left","77px");          
$parent.find('img#photo1').addClass('rotate1');
$parent.find('img#photo2').addClass('rotate2');
$parent.find('img#photo3').addClass('rotate3');
$parent.find('img#photo1').css("left","150px"); 
$parent.find('img#photo3').css("left","50px");
   }
})
.delegate('img', 'mouseleave', function() {
    $('img#photo1').removeClass('rotate1');
        $('img#photo2').removeClass('rotate2');
        $('img#photo3').removeClass('rotate3');
        $('div.namehover').removeClass('rotate3');
 $('div.namehover').css("left","");   


        $('img#photo1').css("left","");
$('img#photo3').css("left","");

});;
});
```

​

html

```
<div style="border:0px;clear:both;padding-bottom:240px;">

 <div class="image_stack" style="margin-left:0px;" >
 <img id="photo1" class="stackphotos" src="http://www.commentsyard.com/cy/01/6474/Mixed%20Flowers%20and%20a%20Bear.jpg"  >
 <img id="photo2" class="stackphotos" src="http://www.commentsyard.com/cy/01/6474/Mixed%20Flowers%20and%20a%20Bear.jpg" >
  <img id="photo3" class="stackphotos"  src="http://www.commentsyard.com/cy/01/6474/Mixed%20Flowers%20and%20a%20Bear.jpg" >

 <div class="namehover"> Perfumes</div>

 </div>
```

css

```
.image_stack img { /* css style for photo stack */
border: none;
text-decoration: none;
position: absolute;
margin-left:0px;
width: 170px;
height: 180px;
}
.image_stack { /* css style for photo stack */
width: 200px;
position: relative;
padding-left:20px;
margin-bottom:40px;
float:left;

}
.image_stack img { /* css style for photo stack */
position: absolute;
border: 4px solid #FFF;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
z-index: 9999;
/* Firefox */
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
/* WebKit */
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
/* Opera */
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
/* Standard */
transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.image_stack #photo1 {  /* position of last photo in the stack */
top: 8px;
left: 108px;
}
.image_stack #photo2 {/* position of middle photo in the stack */
top: 6px;
left: 104px;
}
.image_stack #photo3 {/* position of first photo at the top in the stack */
top: 4px;
left: 100px;
right: 100px; 
}
.image_stack .rotate1 {/* rotate last image 15 degrees to the right */
-webkit-transform: rotate(15deg); /* safari and chrome */
-moz-transform: rotate(15deg);/*firefox browsers */
transform: rotate(15deg);/*other */
-ms-transform:rotate(15deg); /* Internet Explorer 9 */
-o-transform:rotate(15deg); /* Opera */
}
.image_stack .rotate2 {/* css not used*/
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); /* safari and chrome */
-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);/*firefox browsers */
transform: rotate(0deg);/*other */
-ms-transform:rotate(0deg); /* Internet Explorer 9 */
-o-transform:rotate(0deg); /* Opera */
}
.image_stack .rotate3 {/*rotate first image 15 degrees to the left*/
-webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg); /* safari and chrome */
-moz-transform: rotate(-15deg); /*firefox browsers */
transform: rotate(-15deg);/*other */
-ms-transform:rotate(-15deg); /* Internet Explorer 9 */
-o-transform:rotate(-15deg); /* Opera */
cursor: pointer;
}
.namehover{
position:absolute;left:105px;top:167px;z-index:99999;
display:block;background:#333;color:#fff;width:169px;}
```

​

Comment: Please define "works" and "doesn't work".

Comment: What do you mean "but not in browsers"? Jsfiddle is running in your browser.

Comment: you can see the working code in jsfiddle compiler .. but when you use it in a webpage ,it wont works

Answer (score 1):

Is your script located in an external file? Is it on the html page? Type          `console.log("checking script");`at the top of your javascript function, right after `$(document).ready(function() {` . If you are using firebug/chrome developer check your console when you load the page. If you don't see "checking script" in your console line, it's not linked to your html page.

If not, double check your resources. You may have an issue in your file path.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL on line 29 .which is last line

Comment: Did you misplace the log statement? Try it at the top of your function, typed exactly as I have it.

Comment: i used it what exactly you say ,still same error . Could you please try in your browser .

Comment: Can you post the entire html page that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle includes jQuery for you.  Are you *properly* including jQuery in your application?

Look in the browser's JavaScript console for specific JavaScript error messages and post them here.

Comment: yup. i included <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

Comment: What errors do you see in the JavaScript console of your browser?

Comment: actually images must transform when hover, it works in js fiddle compiler , but in the browser there is no transform.

Comment: @BalluRocks, you need to actually debug your application by using your browsers' developer tools and javascript console. Open it when trying your code and see if you get errors. If nothing outputs errors, add breaking points to your code to see what's happening. Without debugging it you may not find the problem. If it works in jsfiddle but not in the browser, something is wrong with your page, not the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include it in your html files. That's probably not happening. You need something like this on your page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: i placed <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the absolute path to the .js files?

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>`

`<!--[if lt IE 9]> <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script> <![endif]-->`

Comment: yup..i used .. you may try this in your browsers .

Answer (score 0):

```
//jquery code below is applicable for the photo stack only . Not for the single image zoom effect
$(document).ready(function() { 
$(".image_stack").delegate('img', 'mouseenter', function() {//when user hover mouse on   image with div id=stackphotos 
    if ($(this).hasClass('stackphotos')) {//
    // the class stackphotos is not really defined in css , it is only assigned  to each images in the photo stack to trigger the mouseover effect on  these photos only 

        var $parent = $(this).parent();
        $parent.find('div.namehover').addClass('rotate3');
$parent.find('div.namehover').css("left","77px");  
$parent.find('img#photo1').addClass('rotate1');//add class rotate1,rotate2,rotate3 to  each image so that it rotates to the correct degree in the correct direction ( 15 degrees  one to the left , one to the right ! )
$parent.find('img#photo2').addClass('rotate2');
$parent.find('img#photo3').addClass('rotate3');
$parent.find('img#photo1').css("left","150px"); // reposition the first and last image 
$parent.find('img#photo3').css("left","50px");

    }
})
.delegate('img', 'mouseleave', function() {// when user removes cursor from the   image stack
    $('img#photo1').removeClass('rotate1');// remove the css class that was   previously added to make it to its original position
        $('img#photo2').removeClass('rotate2');
        $('img#photo3').removeClass('rotate3');
        $('div.namehover').removeClass('rotate3');

        $('img#photo1').css("left","");// remove the css property 'left'   value from the dom
$('img#photo3').css("left","");
$('div.namehover').css("left","");

});;
});
```